# Hash table quadrtc. probing

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, quadratic-probing

**Need an example**

I need to Give the size of the table and the elements I have tried to insert, which I could not insert because of collision after the table is more than half full.

I have tried a few different inputs on the table size, with the function:
h of i (x) = (hash(x) + f(i)) mod table size

f(i)= i^2

I would appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a table of size 7 assume the spots 0, 1, 2, 4 are taken, 3, 5, 6 are free.
Now try to insert an x where hash(x) = 0.

Example: lets take hash(x) = x % 7.

```
Insert 0: hash(0) = 0, this slot is free so insert 0 into slot 0
Insert 1: hash(1) = 1, this slot is free so insert 1 into slot 1
Insert 2: hash(2) = 2, this slot is free so insert 2 into slot 2
Insert 4: hash(4) = 4, this slot is free so insert 4 into slot 4
Insert 7: hash(7) = 0, slot 0 is already taken; start quadratic probing:
(0+1*1)%7 = 1 also taken
(0+2*2)%7 = 4 also taken
(0+3*3)%7 = 2 also taken
(0+4*4)%7 = 2 also taken
(0+5*5)%7 = 4 also taken
(0+6*6)%7 = 1 also taken
...
```

Comment: I did using 53,25,72,10,6,17,26; if it does collide, as the i increases it eventually finds an empty spot to place the next number, I need a sequence of number where it does NOT find a spot to place the next number before the table is filled. That is where I am having issues, seems like every input I try, if it does collide with another value already in the place, as the i increases meaning f(i)=i^2; it always finds a place eventually at some point. I need some sequence of numbers where it never finds a place to add the next element before the table is filled.

Comment: For simplicity, take hash(x) = x % 7. Now insert 0, 1, 2, 4, then try 7.

Comment: that would be linear probing right? Even if I tried that using the linear probing, it would be [x+f(i)] mod 7    where f(i) = i     I would still be able to place 7 in the 5th index

Comment: No, why? The hash gives the initial position to try, this has nothing to do with the probing sequence.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I need a hash table that uses quadratic probing to insert; which is hash(x)= (x+f(i)) mod 7      where f(i)=i^2    ; i starts from 0 increments one every time there is a collision

Comment: so, when inserting I need to use the above probing method(quadratic probing) not hash(x)= x % 7 which is used for separate chaining insertion probe